# Sniff running SQL statement's variable values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging

Is there a way to observe the values of variable inside of a running query.  Let's say that I have a loop that has been running for hours.  I want to see what the value of the variable which was explicitly set in the query for the start of the loop (@start).

Yes, I can determine this by deductive reasoning by looking at the what the procedure is doing (first value inserted/updated, etc), but I'm looking for a way to actually dig into a running query.

Comment: Maybe instead of putting effort into inspecting the loop while it is running you should put that effort into getting rid of the loop.

Comment: `SQL Server Profiler` should help you or add a `Print` or `Select` statement inside loop

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the comment, the loop exists because of vendor code (trigger) which only allows one insert at a time - multiples break the trigger.  Assuming laziness is not appreciated here.

Comment: @SeanLange - What if inside Loop there is no table hit or costly operations

Comment: @prdp Tracing/profiler shows the current running statement, but won't show the values of variables currently executing.  The server knows the values... it should be there somewhere.

Comment: @Prdp the loop itself can be costly. The whole notion of looping is the wrong way to deal with data. Doing things row by agonizing row is slow. Remember the OP said the loop has been running for hours?

Comment: @DanAndrews I didn't assume you were lazy. I was suggesting that getting rid of the loop would be the best course of action. Can you fix the trigger the vendor created so it can handle sets instead of single rows? If not, I would go back to the vendor and ask them to fix it because that kind of trigger is awful.

Comment: @DanAndrews - Am sure profiler shows the variable values as well

Comment: @SeanLange I do not disagree with you, RBAR sucks.  But that's not the question here.

Comment: For your current situation you probably will need to fire up profiler as @Prdp suggested.

Comment: @DanAndrews - Definitely you should think about rewriting the trigger it should run in set based approach.  Better to remove any logic from triggers

Comment: @Prdp I do not disagree, it's horrible.  Rewriting vendor triggers for them usually isn't the way to go.  Either way, that was just an example.  Let's say it could have been anything... I just want to sniff the values of the currently executing stored procedure in memory.  I'll double check tracing it, but it's not going to show the current value (such as when the value increments), it's only going to show the starting and completed command.

Comment: @DanAndrews - Ahh yes, It will show the starting value only my bad missed that

Comment: @DanAndrews - I dont think of any way to do this +1 from myside. Lets see someone can answer

Answer (score 1):

Try [RAISERROR(...) WITH NOWAIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) with a severity <= 10.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @out VARCHAR(4); 

WHILE @i < 100
BEGIN 
    SET @i = @i + 1; 
    SET @out = CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(4));
    RAISERROR (@out, 1, 0 ) WITH NOWAIT;

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:0.250'; -- wait 250 milliseconds
END
```

Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user.

When RAISERROR is run with a severity of 11 or higher in a TRY block, it transfers control to the associated CATCH block. The error is returned to the caller if RAISERROR is run outside the scope of any TRY block, or with a severity of 10 or lower in a TRY block.

`@@ERROR` is set to 0 by default for messages with a severity from 1 through 10.

Comment: That is an interesting way to do it.  Similar to printing the value.  I was hoping for a way to do this from a query who didn't think ahead enough to code bebugging information in it.